# Can't browse Amazon retail site from VPN inside VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vpn, openvpn

I use a VPN to access services in an AWS VPC. I also use this VPN as a gateway to my local internet. The strange thing is that when I'm connected to the VPN, I can't browse amazon.com or amazon.co.uk I can get to the home page and it displays correctly, but whatever I try to do, I get an error 503 - Service Unavailable:
"We're sorry
An error occurred when we tried to process your request.
We're working on the problem and expect to resolve it shortly. Please note that if you were trying to place an order, it will not have been processed at this time. Please try again later.

We apologise for the inconvenience."
Again, this is Amazon's retail/shopping website.
It works fine with the VPN disabled.
What can I do to get this fixed?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It appears that amazon.com prevents access to the IP address range used by Amazon EC2 instances. This is possibly done to prevent scraping of information.

I accessed a page via an EC2 instance and noticed this message as a comment in the beginning of the HTML page:

> To discuss automated access to Amazon data please contact api-services-support@amazon.com.
>
> For information about migrating to our APIs refer to our Marketplace APIs at https://developer.amazonservices.com/ref=rm_5_sv, or our Product Advertising API at https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html/ref=rm_5_ac for advertising use cases.

In fact, I have seen this behaviour on many websites.

While this does not assist with your use-case of sending traffic via your VPN connection to the Internet, at least it explains why it is occurring.